# Azure infra archive and restore

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-backup-vault

We have set up small dev platform on azure which includes servers(sql server, web server)  and azure ML. These are protected by azure VPN gateway. Below are the list of azure components we created and configured . Currently we don't need the dev platform to be available but we will need it after 6 months . so is there any way we could take this complete setup as snap shot and store as image or images  so that when we need we can just restore it with out doing much configuration

dev platform components to archive and restore

1. Virtual networks , sub nets, dns, firewalls
2. VPN gateway , configuration
3. VM with os and server setup
4. sql server with data
5. subscription with custom roles, assignments, cost alerts , dashboards etc

if this is not possible then what are the alternatives
regards,
Suman

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the different Infrastructure as Code options that are available. Easiest way to 'export' the current situation is to generate an [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/overview) of the needed resources by going to the resource group and clicking *Export template* under *Automation*.

> To implement infrastructure as code for your Azure solutions, use Azure Resource Manager templates (ARM templates). The template is a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) file that defines the infrastructure and configuration for your project. The template uses declarative syntax, which lets you state what you intend to deploy without having to write the sequence of programming commands to create it. In the template, you specify the resources to deploy and the properties for those resources.

To increase the functionality options you have, have a look at [Azure Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview).

> We've introduced a new language named Bicep that's used to develop ARM template JSON. Bicep files and JSON templates offer the same capabilities. You can convert templates between the two languages. Bicep provides a syntax that's easier to use for creating templates.

and also

> Bicep is a domain-specific language (DSL) that uses declarative syntax to deploy Azure resources. It provides concise syntax, reliable type safety, and support for code reuse. We believe Bicep offers the best authoring experience for your infrastructure-as-code solutions in Azure.

Be advised: this is meant for the **resources and their configuration** of your environment. For the data side of things, save and/or export the data somewhere you can restore it from easily like Azure Storage.